# Python Collections Duplicates and Sorting

Tags: python, sorting, collections, duplicates

I am collecting the following data for events from iterating through logs:

```
Event_code = 'AA1', other_data='test', more_data='test', time_diff='7'    
Event_code = 'AB2', other_data='test', more_data='test', time_diff='2'
Event_code = 'AH3', other_data='test', more_data='test', time_diff='5'    
Event_code = 'AA1', other_data='test', more_data='test', time_diff='9'
```

I want to collect this data so that the collection only contains the event code with the largest time_diff for a given event_code. So in this case the last AA1 event with a time diff of 9 would replace the earlier AA1 event with a time_diff of 7.

I then want to be able to sort and print based on the time diff, which would give:

```
Event_code = 'AA1', other_data='test', more_data='test', time_diff='9'    
Event_code = 'AH3', other_data='test', more_data='test', time_diff='5'    
Event_code = 'AB2', other_data='test', more_data='test', time_diff='2'
```

This question is more of a theoretical 'how best to do this' rather than being after the exact code. I currently create a dict of dicts with the event_code as the key, then when I add to the dict of dicts I check if the event_code already exists and if the existing time diff is less than that to be added.

My problem with this is that it doesn't seem very efficient or pythonic. And my code is currently only able to sort by event_code.

The pseudo code for this is:

```
for match in log_file:
.....
event_code = regex_extract_from_match
log_time_diff = regex_extract_from_match
if event_code in event_dict:
    if event_dict[event_code]['time_diff'] < log_time_diff :
        event_dict[event_code] = dict(zip([other_data, more_data, time)diff], ['test', 'test', log_time_diff))
else:
    event_dict[event_code] = dict(zip([other_data, more_data, time)diff], ['test', 'test', 'log_time_diff'))
```

....
to sort and print:

```
for event_code in sorted(event_dict):
    print event_code, other_data, more_data, time_diff
```

Comment: Check again yours parentheses and brackets!

Comment: @Farhadix It says pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

Given you have parsed it all into a list, the operation you are doing when reducing the list this way is called reduction, and you should use the reduce() built-in function for building your event dictionary.

Your sort and print code seem sufficiently Pythonic already.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at reduce(). The issue I still have with the above 'code' is that I can only sort by the event_code and not the time_diff.

Comment: Try iterating over something like `sorted(event_dict, key=operator.itemgetter('time_diff'))`